# How to remove a sliding screen door wheel

Tags: screens

I'm trying to remove one of the sliding screen door wheels.  It seems to one of those that is U shaped.   I've looked at various videos and usually you can use a needle nose pliers and it'll come out.   Funny thing is that there is a plastic piece inside that won't allow me to pull forward. It seems that I can only push in which will not remove it.   Question is.... is there a way to remove the wheel correctly?

Comment: Is there a screw visible that may be an adjusting screw? It will be located on the upper narrow edge above the wheels. A picture always helps...

Comment: I took that adjusting screw out so you can slide the wheel part back and forth.  It just won't come out.